# How to get create scripts of sql server CE 2005 Tables

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-ce, smartphone

I am working on Sql server CE 2005. I have created a Database in Sql server CE 2005 now I want to get the scripts so that can use that further???

Is there any way to get create scripts from SQL server CE 2005 dataBase..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a command line utility that allows you to script an entire SQL Server Compact 2005 database (Exportsqlce31.exe) - http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com